# Pasta inacessível no github

Tags: git, github

Estou fazendo o upload do meu site para o github.

Comandos que eu fiz:

```
git init 
git remote origin master URL 
git add --all 
git commit -m "Primeiro Commit" 
git push origin master
```

Porém o git envia todos arquivos e pastas para o github, porém uma pasta em 
especifico chamada "www" é enviada só que ela é inacessível pelo github.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que aparece se você clicar na pasta?

Comment: A pasta não abre

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso acontece pois existe outro "repositório" .git dentro da pasta `www`.

O que você pode fazer é executar:

```
git rm --cached www
```

Ir no diretório `www` e deletar a pasta `.git`, voltar para diretório anterior e executar:

```
git add www
```

Para adicionar a pasta novamente, ai basta enviar para o Github usando:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro passo : Submodule são essas pastas inacessível que voce cita, temos que remover o .git de dentro dela, mas primeiro >>

```
$ git rm --cached 'pasta com submodule'
```

Agora que removemos a pasta com esse submodule, temos que remover o ' .git ' que fica dentro da pasta, pode ser removido assim :

```
$ rm -Rf 'pasta com submodule'/.git
```

Por ultimo sua pasta será atualizada na IDE por realizar esse comando, dai já podemos subi-la novamente, sem esse problema:

```
$ git add 'pasta com submodule'
```

Lembre-se: esteja na raiz do projeto "www" ..
terminando, voce pode excutar :

```
$git push origin master
```

Comment: Não sei por que o -1, esse erro ocorre por subir um pasta cujo github mantém como inacessível _(a pasta que fica com uma seta)_, e o mesmo orienta de seguir esse passo, e como ele não auxilia nas próximas etapas, facilitei o entendimento. Só não esqueça de dar um **git push origin master**